# Error inserting chart in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I have the following code which allows me to create a bar chart

```
var chart = Charts.newBarChart()
.setDataTable(dataTable)
.setTitle("Rain per month");

sheet.insertChart(chart.build());
```

Unfortunately, I get an error saying "Cannot find method insertChart(Chart)".

It seems that the sheet.insertChart function must take an embeddedChart.

How can I turn my chart into an embedded chart so the insertChart function will take it?

Regards
Crouz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods you are using are for adding charts to the [UiApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app).
To add a chart to a google sheet you would use this syntax:

```
 var chart = sheet.newChart()
 .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
 .addRange(sheet.getRange("A1:B4"))
 .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
 .setOption("title", "Dynamic Chart")
 .build();
 sheet.insertChart(chart);
```

This code was taken from [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertChart(EmbeddedChart)) on the Google App Scripts Documentation.

Also, The [DataTable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/data-table) class is used to create charts when adding charts to [html or the UiApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/charts). If you wanted to add a chart to the spreadsheet as if the user had clicked **insert > chart**, you would have to use `getRange` to draw data. If you're drawing data from multiple sources I would suggest combining the data and adding it somewhere in the spreadsheet using `sheet.getRange().setValue()`.

If you wanted to draw data from a seperate google spreadsheet then you could do something like this:

```
//SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl.openById(inset appropriate id here) would work as well
var externalSheets = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(insert appropriate url here).getSheets();
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
 .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
 .addRange(sheets[insert appropriate sheet index here].getRange("A1:B4"))
 .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
 .setOption("title", "Dynamic Chart")
 .build();
 sheet.insertChart(chart);
```

Comment: I cannot use getRange.  It has to be a dataTable as the data is coming from different sheets and needs to be put together into a table first.

Comment: @Crouzilles I've updated my answer to address the use of the DataTable class.